# pygame - problem with killing all sprites with single mouse click

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a shooting game, where you as a player see entire battlefield and your task is to kill enemies that run from left to the right side. Every mouse click is a single shot, that should kill single enemy, but when there are several enemies in one place they all get killed by single mouse click. I'm using pygame.sprite.Group for enemies.

```
def events(self):
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            self.__running = False
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            pos = pg.mouse.get_pos()
            if self.player.shot():
                for enemy in self.enemies:
                    if enemy.rect.collidepoint(pos):
                        enemy.decreaseHp(self.player.getDamage())
```

Is there a way to kill single sprite with single mouse click when parts of their sprites have the same coordinates?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it. This code works well, but it's not what I want

Comment: Like what Rabbid76 said, break out of the loop after you killed the enemy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to kill 1 enemy, the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) the loop after the 1st enemy was shoot:

```py
for enemy in self.enemies:
    if enemy.rect.collidepoint(pos):
        enemy.decreaseHp(self.player.getDamage())
        break
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy and I couldn't figure it out. Thank you so much!